# Fail to delete imported users from Oracle configured with Liferay

Tags: oracle, ldap, liferay, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I have imported users in liferay(configured with oracle database) using OpenDJ, there are users in oracle database and also displayed on Liferay but when I tried to delete the users from liferay its not deleting it from oracle database.I don't understand the problem. Any Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please include _how_ you deleted the users and _how_ do you check that the users are still in the database?

Comment: As there's no clarification on the comment above after 1.5 months, I'm voting to close this question now